# Coloring of ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

Is it possible to get this row coloring in the WPF Listbox?

White
LightGray
Gray
White
LightGray
etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use the AlternationCount Property of the ListBox. Something like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then just set the AlternationCount on your ListBox

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="3"
         ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But I have 2 Listboxes in the same form, both get this and both of the Listboxes gets this coloring

Comment: This style is targetting ListBoxItem so it will applicable to all the listbox.